# ForEach Detecting Last In Sub ForEach

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I have a nested ForEach that is showing categories of items. I am trying to figure out how to detect the last element in the item loop that matches the category, so I can choose not to show a visual element on the screen.

Here's a small example:

```
ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in
    Text("\(category.name)")
    ForEach(items, id: \.self) { item in
        if item.category == category {
            Text("\(item.name)")
        }
        if item != items.last {
            Divider()
        }
    }
}
```

The issue is that the items array has all the items in it and not just the items that match with the category. So, I need to somehow detect the last loop of the sub ForEach in order to determine whether to display a Divider.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You ought to be able to keep things straightforward by filtering your items array outside of the `ForEach(items)` loop. For example:

```swift
var body: some View {
  ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in 
    let categoryItems = items.filter { $0.category == category }
    ForEach(categoryItems, id: \.self) { item in 
      Text(item.name)
      if item != categoryItems.last {
        Divider()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know how many categories and items you're likely to have, but for long lists this could slow down - you'll run a filter across the whole items list once for every category. If this becomes an issue, you could construct a temporary variable that groups everything together once. `Dictionary(grouping:by:)` will do this for you, although it won't guarantee the order in which category keys are listed:

```swift
let groupedItems = Dictionary(grouping: items, by: \.category)
```

This will produce a dictionary that looks like:

```
[ category1: [item1, item3, item5, item8],
  category3: [item2, item6, item7],
  category2: [item4] ]
```

Then in your view, you can use `ForEach` to loop through the categories in the correct order, and look up the relevant list of items. Note that if a category doesn't have any items, it won't appear in the dictionary, so we need to account for that possibility:

```swift
ForEach(categories, id: \.self) { category in 
  let categoryItems = groupedItems[category, default: []]
  ForEach(categoryItems, id: \.self) { item in 
      Text(item.name)
      if item != categoryItems.last {
        Divider()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Creating the sub array is exactly what I was looking for. I was thinking along this line yesterday but not as simply as you stated it. Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't perfectly mirror your situation, but the concept should apply -- you can use `enumerated` and check the indices:

```
struct Category : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Item : Identifiable, Hashable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct ContentView: View {
    var categories: [Category] = [.init(name: "1"),.init(name: "2"), .init(name: "3")]
    var items: [Item] = [.init(name: "1"), .init(name: "2"), .init(name: "3")]
    
    var body: some View {
        ForEach(Array(categories.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (categoryIndex, category) in
            Text("\(category.name)")
            ForEach(Array(items.enumerated()), id: \.1.id) { (itemIndex, item) in
                Text("\(item.name)")
                if categoryIndex == categories.count - 1, itemIndex == items.count - 1 {
                    Divider()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```